# Compile-Time vs Run-Time in Java?

Tags: java

I have one doubt in these two terms.
I created one class Demo.java & i took one instance variable in class Demo.
Point to be noticed: I am not going to run my program, "i will just compile my program" & my question is instance variable which i have declared in my class, Will it take memory into heap or not ?
According to me "I think no" but my friend is arguing with me who has four years of experience in java. I'm just fresher that is why i'm confused because of his words.

```
class Demo
{
int a=10;
}
```

javac Demo.java

Comment: A program only uses memory when it runs. If you don't run the program, it will not use any memory.

Comment: yeah i am saying same thing but my friend is arguing with me who has four years of experience in java. I'm just fresher that is why i'm confused because of his words.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask your friend what he means exactly. Perhaps he means that the compiler itself is a program and will take memory to process that code?

Comment: Uhmm, i think he just want to bother you

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running a program it will not use heap memory

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense, probably because you don't know what running and compiling means. Running and compiling are two completely different things in most languages, not just in java. Basically you compile the source code to machine code, which is then executed by the compiler. So while you can compile a source, it does not mean you have to run it Compile time is of no relevance to the end-user, because you barely have a program that needs to be recompiled on each run when deployed.

Comment: Excuted by the compiler?